sigma-algebra vs sigma-frame
A $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ on a set $X$ is a family of subsets of $X$ such that:

$\phi\in \mathcal{A}$.
$\mathcal{A}$ is closed under countable unions.
$\mathcal{A}$ is closed under complementation.

Loosely speaking, A $\sigma$-algebra lies between Boolean algebra and complete Boolean algebra.
A $\textit{frame}$ (=pointfree topology) is a complete lattice in which finite meets distributes over arbitrary joins.
In particular, A $\sigma$-frame is a $\sigma$-complete (closed under countable joins) bounded lattice $L$ in which finite meets distributes over countable joins. That is,
$x\wedge \bigvee_i y_i= \bigvee_i (x\wedge y_i)$.
Clearly, a $\sigma$-algebra is an example of a $\sigma$-frame.
Another good source of $\sigma$-frames are $Coz(C(X))=\{Coz(f)\colon f\in C(X)\}$, where $Coz(f)=\{x\in X\colon f(x)\neq 0\}$ and $C(X)$ is the rings of continuous real-valued functions on a topological space $X$ with pointwise addition and pointwise multiplication.
One difference we can observe between a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ and $Coz(C(X))$ is that although they are both $\sigma$-frames, a $\sigma$-algebra is closed under countable intersections (countable meets), but $Coz(C(X))$ may not be closed under countable intersections and may not be complemented (Take $X$ for which $Coz(f)$ is not clopen).
Alex Simpson, in this paper, has studied the prospect of measure theory in terms of $\sigma$-frames.

Topologically, what is the main difference between the two $\sigma$-frames I have discussed?


Why the complementation property is not needed to study measure theory on locales?

